# Echo a txt file in data-caption

Tags: php, html, ckeditor, echo, zurb-foundation

I am trying to echo in php the image description in the data-caption of the clearing image gallery of Foundation3 but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
<li class="clearing-feature">
                    <a href="administration/galleri/kcfinder/upload/images/Galleri1/1.jpg">
                    <img data-caption="<?php echo $myDataBild1 ?>;" src="kcfinder/upload/images/Galleri1/1.jpg"></a>
</li>
```

This is not working. The image gallery is still working correctly but the caption in this picture is not showing. How can I correct this?

**NOTE:** The php $myDataBild1 is a txt file with text inserted via CKEditor and it is working just fine. Let me know if you need the code and the variable is shown if I echo it anywhere else.

Comment: How looks compiled source code? Is data-caption filled correctly? Escaped correctly (quotes for example)? Is something in error console in your browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Misplaced comma - also try by using [addslashes](https://www.php.net/addslashes).

```
<img data-caption="<?php echo addslashes($myDataBild1); ?>" src="kcfinder/upload/images/Galleri1/1.jpg"></a>
```

Comment: So simple! Truly thankful! These are the things one doesn't see because it is easy to fall into a "bubble" when one is developing a system for so long... Truly thankful once again!

Comment: @viriato - we've all been there, glad to help.